# Why exists the SigningCertificateFile in ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2

Tags: saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

In the exemple code of MVC, is used the itfoxtec.identity.saml2.testwebapp_Certificate.pfx:

https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebApp/App_Data/itfoxtec.identity.saml2.testwebapp_Certificate.pfx

in this part:

https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/10cba6a1a8be236046b9caab0651eba9002b55ee/test/TestWebApp/App_Start/IdentityConfig.cs#L29

But I don't understand the why i need this, because already had the certificate of the IdP, and if there is some way that i don't use this.

Answer (score 3):

The IdP certificate is used to sign the `authn response` (SAML 2.0 token) from the IdP.

The SAML 2.0 standard says that a rp (relying party) like the TestWebApp need to sign `logout request`. the TestWebApp sample application sign the request with the `itfoxtec.identity.saml2.testwebapp_Certificate.pfx` certificate.

It is not required for a rp to sign `login request` and therefore the `itfoxtec.identity.saml2.testwebapp_Certificate.pfx` certificate is not required if the rp only do login and not logout.